# how do i load swipe to refresh data at top listview android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Currently, my listview shows me current data. On Swipe, it will load old data from the server and store first old data and after current data. load server data at the top while swipe to refresh data. it is no updating data at the top level. Help me out for this situation. every time load data on top. and show loader while refreshing data while swipe to top to bottom.

Thank you in advance. Here I am posting my code for review

```
public class CommmentActivity extends Activity{

String Curl;
boolean mBuzy;
String UserId;
String VidoId;
String strComment;
EditText etComment;
String mPositionId = "";
String strfriendsSyncDate;
ArrayAdapter<String> mentionList;
ListCommentAdapter commentAdapter;
AutoCompleteTextView aCompletView;
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
List<CommentListInfo> list_CommentInfo = new ArrayList<CommentListInfo>();
ArrayList<MentionBeanClass> mList;
MentionBeanClass addMention;
List<String> SuggetionList;



ImageView IvAddComment;
ListView CommentList;
SessionCreator m_session;
boolean m = false;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.commentvideo_main);


    SuggetionList =  new ArrayList<String>();
    Curl = GlobalMethod.TokenGenerator() + "&action=getCommentsVideo";

    Intent data = getIntent();
    UserId = data.getStringExtra("userId");
    VidoId = data.getStringExtra("videoId");
    init();

    strfriendsSyncDate = m_session.getfriendsSyncDate();
    new CommentsDetail().execute(UserId,VidoId,strfriendsSyncDate,mPositionId,Curl,"1");
    ArratListBeans.setArMentionList(mList);


    commentAdapter = new ListCommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list_CommentInfo);
    CommentList.setAdapter(commentAdapter); 



    CommentList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (scrollState) {
            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:{


                Log.d("ScrollStateCheck", ""+scrollState);



                break;
            }

            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
            {
                mBuzy = true;
                int count = CommentList.getCount();

                if(CommentList.getFirstVisiblePosition()==0){
                    CommentListInfo c;
                    c = (CommentListInfo) CommentList.getAdapter().getItem(CommentList.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                    mPositionId = c.CommentId;
                    Log.d("mpositionId", mPositionId);
                    String strUrl = GlobalMethod.TokenGenerator() + "&action=getCommentsVideo";
                    new CommentsDetail().execute(UserId,VidoId,strfriendsSyncDate,c.CommentId,strUrl,"1");
                }

                break;
            }

            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:{
                mBuzy = true;
                break;
            }


            default:
                break;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    });



IvAddComment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            strComment = etComment.getText().toString();
            etComment.getText().clear();
            String strUrl = GlobalMethod.TokenGenerator() + "&action=addCommentsVideo";

            new CommentsDetail().execute(UserId,VidoId,strComment,strUrl,"0");
            new CommentsDetail().execute(UserId,VidoId,strfriendsSyncDate,Curl,"1");
            commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });



}

private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    m_session = new SessionCreator(getApplicationContext());
    etComment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etComments);
    CommentList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvLatestComments);
    IvAddComment = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.addComment);
    mList = new ArrayList<MentionBeanClass>();
}

public class CommentsDetail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ServiceHandler serviceClient;
        String mJsonString;

        try{

            String userId = (String)params[0];
            String vId = (String)params[1];


                String syncdate = (String)params[2];
                String startPosition = (String)params[3];
                String strUrl = (String)params[4];

                List<NameValuePair> paramsNameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userId));
                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("videoId", vId));
                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startFrom", startPosition));
                paramsNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("friendsSyncDate", syncdate));

                serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
                mJsonString = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(strUrl,
                        ServiceHandler.POST, paramsNameValuePairs);

                Log.i("---->>>>>>>>>>", paramsNameValuePairs + "");


        Log.d("Response Json-----------------------",mJsonString );


        return mJsonString;

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unchecked", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        try{
        if (result != null) {
            JSONObject responsJsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) responsJsonObj
                    .optJSONObject("data");

            try {
                String str = jsonObj.getString("error");
                if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                    // error
                    //Toast.makeText(NewsfeedActivity.this, jsonObj.getString("error"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                Log.d("jex ------>", "" + je.getMessage());
                try {
                    String str = jsonObj.getString("message");
                    Log.d("message=", "" + str);
                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("comments")) {
                            JSONArray colArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("comments");
                            Log.d("Colunm Array", ""+colArray);
                            int nComments = colArray.length();
                            Log.d("# comments", "" + nComments);
                            for(int i=0; i<nComments; i++){
                                JSONObject obj = colArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Gson Comments = new Gson();
                                String strComments = Comments.toJson(obj);
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + obj.toString());               
                                CommentListInfo cmtInfo = new CommentListInfo();                
                                cmtInfo.c_userId = obj.getString("userId");
                                cmtInfo.c_name = obj.getString("name");
                                cmtInfo.DateAdded = obj.getString("dateAdded");
                                cmtInfo.CommentId = obj.getString("commentId");
                                cmtInfo.CommentText = obj.getString("text");
                                cmtInfo.ImageUrl = obj.getString("imageLink");
                                list_CommentInfo.add(cmtInfo);  
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("addPosition")) {
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + jsonObj.toString());   
                                Log.d("Add Position", jsonObj.getString("addPosition"));
                        }
                    }

                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("mentions")) {
                            JSONArray colArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("mentions");
                            Log.d("Colunm Array", ""+colArray);
                            int nMention = colArray.length();
                            Log.d("# mentions", "" + nMention);
                            for(int i=0; i<nMention; i++){
                                JSONObject obj = colArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + obj.toString());   
                                mList.add(new MentionBeanClass(obj.getString("id"), obj.getString("name")));
                                Log.d("Mention Info", "Id : "+obj.getString("id")+"   Name : "+obj.getString("name"));
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("videoUserData")) {
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + jsonObj.toString());   
                                Log.d("videoUserData"," "+ jsonObj.getString("videoUserData"));
                        }
                    }



                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("friendsAdded")) {

                            JSONArray colArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("friendsAdded");
                            String json = colArray.toString();

                            Log.d("Colunm Array", ""+colArray);
                            int nfriendsAdded = colArray.length();
                            Log.d("# friendsAdded", "" + nfriendsAdded);
                            for(int i=0; i<nfriendsAdded; i++){
                                JSONObject obj = colArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + obj.toString());   

                                String id = obj.getString("userId");
                                String name = obj.getString("name");
                                String imgUrl = obj.getString("imageLink");

                                db.addCustomer(new FriendListInfo(id, name, imgUrl));

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("friendsDeleted")) {
                            JSONArray colArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("friendsDeleted");
                            Log.d("Colunm Array", ""+colArray);
                            int nfriendsDeleted = colArray.length();
                            Log.d("# friendsDeleted", "" + nfriendsDeleted);


                            for(int i=0; i<nfriendsDeleted; i++){
                                JSONObject obj = colArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + obj.toString());   
                            }
                        }else{
                            Log.d("Delete Friends", " No Deleted List");
                        }
                    }
                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("friendsUpdated")) {
                            JSONArray colArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("friendsUpdated");
                            Log.d("Colunm Array", ""+colArray);
                            int nfriendsUpdated = colArray.length();
                            Log.d("# friendsDeleted", "" + nfriendsUpdated);
                            for(int i=0; i<nfriendsUpdated; i++){
                                JSONObject obj = colArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + obj.toString());   
                            }
                        }else{
                            Log.d("Update Friends", " No Updated List");
                        }
                    }

                    if ( str != null || str.length() != 0) {
                        // VALID RESPONSE, NOW PARSE IT
                        if (jsonObj.has("friendsSyncDate")) {
                            Log.d("# friendsDeleted", "" + jsonObj);
                                Log.d("# obj=", "" + jsonObj.toString());   

                                String myString = m_session.getfriendsSyncDate();
                                Log.d("myString", myString);

                                m_session.putfriendsSyncDate(jsonObj.getString("friendsSyncDate"));
                                Log.d("Sync Date "," "+jsonObj.getString("friendsSyncDate"));
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException je2) {
                    je2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }



}

}
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: here posted my code  @NehaAgarwal

Comment: @VanrajVyas in this case you might have to sort your adapter data . and after sorting call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter

Comment: You should make your question more explicit. Like in a sentence with a question mark (and please not something useless like "Can anyone help?", but something like "How do I fill the old data after the new data in my listview?"  )

Answer (score 0):

Add adapter-listview update code

```
case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
            {
                mBuzy = true;
                int count = CommentList.getCount();

                if(CommentList.getFirstVisiblePosition()==0){
                    CommentListInfo c;
                    c = (CommentListInfo) CommentList.getAdapter().getItem(CommentList.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                    mPositionId = c.CommentId;
                    Log.d("mpositionId", mPositionId);
                    String strUrl = GlobalMethod.TokenGenerator() + "&action=getCommentsVideo";
                    new CommentsDetail().execute(UserId,VidoId,strfriendsSyncDate,c.CommentId,strUrl,"1");
CommentList.setAdapter(commentAdapter); //update code
                }
```